# Classic ASP Split DateTIME to String

Tags: datetime, asp-classic

I have a DateTime value pulled from a field in an MSSQL database  I want to split this and remove all delimiters so that I have just a string of the date.

```
So: 2012-11-06 14:36:20.810
Becomes: 20121106143620810
```

Ideally, I don't want the milliseconds either......

```
So: 2012-11-06 14:36:20.810
Becomes: 20121106143620
```

I am using Classic ASP for this application.

Any ideas?

Comment: Grab everything to the left of the period, and then replace all hyphens, spaces and colons with an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
dateFromDB = "2012-11-06 14:36:20.810"
formatedDate = Replace(dateFromDB, "-","")
formatedDate = Replace(formatedDate, ":","")
formatedDate = Replace(formatedDate, " ","")
formatedDate = Left(formatedDate, Len(formatedDate)-4)
```

Of course you can optimize it in various ways, but this will get the job done

Comment: How would I write that back to a hidden form field? Something like: <%=formatedDate%>?

Comment: Sorry, managed to do that bit.  How would I remove the millisecond part entirely? LEFT caused an error, so removed that out.

Comment: Done it! `formatedDate = LEFT(formatedDate, (LEN(formatedDate)-4))`.  Thanks for the help @Blachshma

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep this value in string and remove all special characters.
2. If you don't want milliseconds then remove the last 3 characters also.